# Linq question with sorting words from list

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I Need to do 4 things with a list.

- Sort only words starting with "A"
- Sort only words starting with "B"
- Sort only words starting with "C"
- Sort all other words together.

I did it as following. But I have no idea how to express myself for other words
need something like:

```
where o.ToUpper().StartWith(o!=(A) StartWith(o!=(B) StartWith(o!=(C))
```

Is there any way to do it?

Imagine that user input  5 words:  Airplane , Ball, Cigar, Pear, Toilet and I want to Write it like   Words with A:  AirPlane    ,  Words with B: Ball  , Words with C: Cigar  , Other Words: Pear, Toilet.

```
var listA =            
(from a in words
             where a.ToUpper().StartsWith("A")

             select a).ToList();

            foreach (string i in listaA)

            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
```

Comment: I read your question three times and I still do not understand it. Can you maybe edit your question and add sample input and output?

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: if you do LINQ 4 times, it is much slower than one regular for-each loop

Comment: What u mean? All lists in 1 foreach?

Comment: I mean, instead of making linq doing loop for you, you write explicit loop. Then you only need 1 loop instead of 4. And BTW, if you answer someones comment , you need to add person's @userId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var wordsStartingWithA = words.Where(i => i.ToUpper().StartsWith("A")).ToList();
// same for B & C

var otherWords = words.Where(i => !new[] { "A", "B", "C" }.Any(i.ToUpper().StartsWith)).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

After thinking about it, I think this would be a much cleaner approach:

```
var wordGroups = words.GroupBy(i => char.ToUpper(i[0])).ToDictionary(i => i.Key, j => j.ToList());

var wordsStartingWithA = wordGroups['A'];
// same for B & C

var otherWords = wordGroups.Where(i => !new[] { 'A', 'B', 'C' }.Any(i.Key.Equals))
                           .SelectMany(i => i.Value).ToList();
```

This way all words are sorted into groups based on their first letter, so you can get all words starting with *Z* by doing `wordGroups['Z']`.

Comment: thanks alot. Thats it. Can you help me make query expresion instead of fluence of last line.

Comment: @MatejOsijek do you mean like this? `var otherWords = words.Where(i => !i.ToUpper().StartsWith("A") && !i.ToUpper().StartsWith("B") && !i.ToUpper().StartsWith("C")).ToList();`

Comment: Thats it. Im really thankfull to you. Have a nice day. You helped me alooooot ;) <3